# JS Convert function to one line without if/else

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

How to convert this function without using if/else?

```
function Menu() {
if (!currentUser || currentUser.getValue == 7)  {
    return false
} else {
    return true
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator, as shown below:

```js
function isValueSeven(val) {
  return !!(val?.getValue() === 7);
}

console.log(isValueSeven({ getValue: () => 7 }));
console.log(isValueSeven({ getValue: () => 8 }));
console.log(isValueSeven(null));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just do ?

```js
function validateMenu() {
  return p.currentUser && p.currentUser.getValue('id') !== 7
}
```

I really don't understand why would you want to use a callback or a Promise for this case. There is nothing asynchronous involved, only two simple conditions being checked.

You might want to read a bit more about callbacks and Promises.

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
let showMenu = (!p.currentUser || p.currentUser.getValue('id') === 7) ? false : true;
```

If you want to use promises you can

```
function validateMenu() {
    return new Promises((resolve, reject) => {

        if (!p.currentUser || p.currentUser.getValue('id') === 7) {
            resolve(false)
        } else {
            resolve(true)
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need [**`if...else`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement or [**conditional (ternary) operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), you could just use [**arrow function expression**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [**logical operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators):

```
const Menu = () => !!currentUser && currentUser.getValue('id') !== 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

why not pass the user to a function like this

```
const validateMenu = (user) => (!user || user.getValue('id') === 7) ? false : true;
```

then you can call `validateMenu(p.currentUser)`

Answer (score 0):

In function, like this

```
function validateMenu() {
return !(!p.currentUser || p.currentUser.getValue('id') === 7)
}
```

In variable, like below:

```
let showMenu = !(!p.currentUser || p.currentUser.getValue('id') === 7)
```

You don’t need to write return while declaring variables.